# Does WordPress preload pages?

Tags: wordpress, apache, access-log

While surfing my site and reviewing my server access logs, it appears the 'next' page in my site is served along with the page I navigated to (one click, two pages).  Sometimes it does it in order, other times it appears to be random, grabbing unlisted pages and serving those.

That is, I click on the 'about' page, and the logs report serving 'about' AND 'contact'.

There's nothing visibly wrong on the front end, and everything validates.  I'm using HighslideJS for my gallery which uses preloaders for images, and I looked into potential bugs with WP-supercache but haven't found an answer.

This doesn't seem like normal behavior since it's polluting my logs.  Any leads to follow would be appreciated.

Comment: Might want to investigate from the client side as well, with a tool like Firebug et al.

Comment: @user1508153 Are you using google chrome?

Comment: Do you make ajax calls? Check Firebug Console!

Answer (score 1):

That's your web browser pre-fetching the next page. WordPress is just letting your browser know about which page is next, using a [link rel='next' element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3). If you want to prevent this, add this to your functions.php file in your theme:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```